# Integrability of time differences via bootstraping?

Tags: integration, proof-verification

the question is somehow inspired by the Alt-Luckhaus paper (Lemma 1.5)

Let $B:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuos and nonnegative, $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a bounded domain, $h,T>0$. Let $u_0:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $B(u_0)$ is integrable.
Let $u:\Omega\times[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ be measurable and set $u(t)=u_0$ for $-h<t<0$ and finally let $g\in L^1(\Omega\times(0,T))$.

Now, from somewhere I receive the estimate
$$B(u(x,t))-B(u(x,t-h))\leq g(x,t)$$
and I want to show that $B(u(x,t))\in L^1(\Omega\times (0,T))$.

Can one show this simply by bootstrapping/a recursive argument? I.e. for $0<t<h$ we use that $B(u(x,t-h))=B(u_0(x))$ to obtain
$$0\leq B(u(x,t))\leq g(x,t)+B(u_0(x))$$ and hence $B\in L^1((0,h)\times \Omega)$. Now iterating this estimate (e.g. on $(h,2h)$ we find that $B(u,t-h)$ is integrable by the step just shown) yields integrability on the whole space-time cylinder.

Is there any flaw in the argument? Unfortunately, I haven't seen this before though it really looks like immitatin of piecewise constant time discretization method.

Comment: Is there really nobody that could comment on this? Is the question unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is completely clear; I think people thought the term 'bootstrapping' was something technical they hadn't heard of. But yes, your method makes sense and is correct given the assumptions. You are saying the translation by a fixed distance increases the integral of the base function by a bounded amount, and that you need only finitely many translations to cover the whole domain. This is comoletely reasonable.

Comment: good answer; yes, I think that "via recursive argument" might sound more familiar than "via bootstrapping" to many people, but I agree that the important details of OP's argument are correct.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the question.